# How to redirect page reload to a specific route?

Tags: angularjs

How can I set up my AngularJS app to redirect to a specific route whenever a user clicks on page reload regardless of which ng-route the app is currently situated?

For example, if the user is at '/phones/:phoneId', when the user reloads the page the route will be set to '/phones'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the $location from a [run block](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module):

> Run blocks - get executed after the injector is created and are used
>   to kickstart the application.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp');

myApp.run(function($location) {
    $location.path("/phones");
});
```